# Multitouch on GearVR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

I understand that it's possible for a GearVR to distinguish between a "tap" and a "swipe". But is it possible to distinguish between a one finger tap and a two finger tap?

Comment: No, it is very clear in its api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the touchpad on the GearVR presents touches via the Mouse input:

Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) / Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)